# AWS: RDS instance(s) and connecting from remote machine

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I'm moving a site over to AWS.  It's on the Amazon-flavored Linux distro, using MySQL. I vaguely remember setting it up a couple of months ago (been busy), and allowed access from my elastic IP.  I was wanting to add another IP (home) so I can connect it directly.  Caveat: when I go to RDS from the AWS dashboard, it takes me to the Get Started wizard, like it wants to create another RDS instance.

The Database is running fine.  I've been accessing it from my AWS server with zero problems.  However, I want to do an admit task or two on it as mentioned above, and that's not flying.  Shouldn't the RDS instance show up when I choose RDS from the control panel?

Comment: Check your region. RDS is not global.

Comment: That got it.  Had to go back to the console.  All good now!